# How to combine two textplot_xray graphs into one？

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to combine two `textplot_xray` graphs using `.` but unsuccessful.

```
library("quanteda.textplots")   
init <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
        par(mfrow=c(2,1))
        textplot_xray(kwic(qcorp_tokens, pattern= "like"))
        textplot_xray(kwic(qcorp_tokens, pattern= "cats"))
```

Comment: Can you try `textplot_xray(kwic(qcorp_tokens, "like"), kwic(qcorp_tokens, "cats"))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use all options that can handle ggplot graphics. Check the mentioned packages below, their vignettes and choose one.

**gridExtra**

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textplots)

toks <- tokens(data_char_sampletext)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
textplot_xray(kwic(toks, pattern = "policy")),
textplot_xray(kwic(toks, pattern = "economy"))
)
```

**patchwork**

```
library(patchwork)

p1 <- textplot_xray(kwic(toks, pattern = "policy")) 
p2 <- textplot_xray(kwic(toks, pattern = "economy"))

# like gridExtra as above
p1 / p2

# next to each other
p1 + p2
```

**cowplot**

```
library(cowplot)

# using p1 and p2 from above
plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a direct comparison, `textplot_xray()` will combine multiple kwic objects into a single plot.  You can do this either by creating a single kwic on multiple pattern elements, or by sending any number of kwic objects to the plot function.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.2.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library("quanteda.textplots")

toks <- tokens(data_corpus_inaugural[1:5])

textplot_xray(
  kwic(toks, pattern = "war"),
  kwic(toks, pattern = "peace")
)
```

[image]

```r
# same result
textplot_xray(kwic(toks, pattern = c("war", "peace")))
```

[image]